# C Program with fork and pipe

Tags: c, io, pipe, fork

I'm at the beginning with these things and I'm trying to do this exercise but I'm clearly doing something wrong but I don't know what.

*Write a C program that takes 4 file names as parameters. The program will have to create 3 child processes. Each child will read three characters from his file and communicate them to his father via PIPE. The father will check the characters read, if the sequence of 3 characters received by the 3 children is the same, this will be printed in the fourth file. As soon as one of the children finishes reading its file, all other child processes must also end.*

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
void primoFiglio(char *file,int pipe[]);
void secondoFiglio(char *file ,int pipe[]);
void terzoFiglio(char *file ,int pipe[]);

void main(int argc,char **argv){
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t processi[3];
    int pipe1[2],pipe2[2],pipe3[2],n1,n2,n3;
    int status;
    int fd;
    char buffer1[10],buffer2[10],buffer3[10];
        if(argc!=5){
        printf("Numero errato di parametri, riprovare.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        if(pipe(pipe1)<0||pipe(pipe2)<0||pipe(pipe3)<0){
            perror("Pipe error");
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            if((pid=fork())<0){
                perror("Fork");
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                if(pid==0){
                    close(pipe1[0]);
                    primoFiglio(argv[1],pipe1);
                }
                else{
                    processi[0]=pid;
                    if((pid=fork())<0){
                        perror("Fork");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(pid==0){
                            close(pipe2[0]);
                            secondoFiglio(argv[2],pipe2);
                        }
                        else{
                            processi[1]=pid;
                            if((pid=fork())<0){
                                perror("Fork");
                                exit(1);
                            }
                            else{
                                if(pid==0){
                                    close(pipe3[0]);
                                    terzoFiglio(argv[3],pipe3);
                                }
                                else{
                                    processi[2]=pid;
                                    fd=open(argv[4],O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_CREAT,0666);
                                    if(fd<0){
                                        perror("File");
                                        exit(1);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        close(pipe1[1]);
                                        close(pipe2[1]);
                                        close(pipe3[1]);
                                        while((n1=read(pipe1[0],buffer1,3)>0)&&(n2=read(pipe2[0],buffer2,3)>0)&&(n3=read(pipe3[0],buffer3,3)>0)){
                                            if(n1==3&&n2==3&&n3==3){
                                                printf("%c %c %c\n",buffer1[0],buffer2[0],buffer3[0]);
                                                if(buffer1[0]==buffer2[0]&&buffer2[0]==buffer3[0]){
                                                    if(buffer1[1]==buffer2[1]&&buffer2[1]==buffer3[1]){
                                                        if(buffer1[2]==buffer2[2]&&buffer2[2]==buffer3[2]){
                                                            write(fd,buffer1,n1);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        close(pipe1[0]);
                                        close(pipe2[0]);
                                        close(pipe3[0]);
                                        close(fd);
                                        if(wait(&status)!=-1){
                                            if(status>>8==2){
                                                kill(processi[1],SIGKILL);
                                                kill(processi[2],SIGKILL);

                                            }
                                            else if(status>>8==3){
                                                kill(processi[0],SIGKILL);
                                                kill(processi[2],SIGKILL);
                                            }

                                            else if(status>>8==4){
                                                kill(processi[0],SIGKILL);
                                                kill(processi[1],SIGKILL);
                                            }

                                        exit(0);
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void primoFiglio(char *file ,int pipe[]){
    int fd,nread;
    char buffer[10];
    fd=open(file,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0){
        perror("File");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        while((nread=read(fd,buffer,3))>0){
            if(nread==3){
                write(pipe[1],buffer,nread);
            }
        }
        close(fd);
        printf("Primo figlio term\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}
void secondoFiglio(char *file ,int pipe[]){
    int fd,nread;
    char buffer[10];
    fd=open(file,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0){
        perror("File");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        while((nread=read(fd,buffer,3))>0){
            if(nread==3){
                 write(pipe[1],buffer,nread);
            }
        }
        close(fd);
        printf("Secondo figlio term\n");
        exit(3);
    }

}
void terzoFiglio(char *file ,int pipe[]){
    int fd,nread;
    char buffer[10];
    fd=open(file,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0){
        perror("File");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        while((nread=read(fd,buffer,3))>0){
            if(nread==3){
                 write(pipe[1],buffer,nread);
            }
        }
        close(fd);
        printf("Terzo figlio term\n");
        exit(4);
    }
}
```

Father can't read 3 characters from each pipe (only one) so it doesn't write anything into fourth file.
Any tips?

**EDIT**
Thank you, your answers helped me a lot
I tried to improve my code and now it works
What do you think?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

void child(char *file,int pipe[]);


int main(int argc,char **argv){
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t process[3];
    int pipe1[2],pipe2[2],pipe3[2],n1,n2,n3;
    int status;
    int fd;
    char buffer1[10],buffer2[10],buffer3[10];
    if(argc!=5){
        printf("Wrong number of parameters\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pipe(pipe1)<0||pipe(pipe2)<0||pipe(pipe3)<0){
            perror("Pipe error");
            exit(1);
    }
    else if((pid=fork())<0){
                perror("Fork");
                exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid==0){
        child(argv[1],pipe1);
    }
    else{
        process[0]=pid;
        if((pid=fork())<0){
            perror("Fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid==0){
            close(pipe1[0]); 
            close(pipe1[1]);
            child(argv[2],pipe2);
        }
        else{
            process[1]=pid;
            if((pid=fork())<0){
                perror("Fork");
                exit(1);
            }
            else if(pid==0){
                close(pipe2[0]); 
                close(pipe2[1]);
                child(argv[3],pipe3);
            }
            else{
                process[2]=pid;
                fd=open(argv[4],O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_CREAT,0666);
                if(fd<0){
                    perror("File");
                    exit(1);
                }
                    close(pipe1[1]);
                    close(pipe2[1]);
                    close(pipe3[1]);
                    while((n1=read(pipe1[0],buffer1,3))>2&&(n2=read(pipe2[0],buffer2,3))>2&&(n3=read(pipe3[0],buffer3,3))>2){
                        printf("Reading...\n");
                        if(memcmp(buffer1,buffer2,3)==0&&memcmp(buffer2,buffer3,3)==0)
                            write(fd,buffer1,n1);
                        pid=waitpid(0,&status,WNOHANG); 
                        if(pid==process[0]){ 
                            kill(process[1],SIGKILL);
                            kill(process[2],SIGKILL);
                        }
                        else if(pid==process[1]){
                            kill(process[0],SIGKILL);
                            kill(process[2],SIGKILL);
                        }
                        else if(pid==process[2]){
                            kill(process[0],SIGKILL);
                            kill(process[1],SIGKILL);
                        }


                    }

                close(pipe1[0]);
                close(pipe2[0]);
                close(pipe3[0]);
                close(fd);
                exit(0);


            }
        }
    }    
}

void child(char *file ,int pipe[]){
    int fd,nread;
    char buffer[10];
    fd=open(file,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0){
        perror("File");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((nread=read(fd,buffer,3))>0){
        if(nread==3){
            write(pipe[1],buffer,nread);
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    exit(0);


}
```

Comment: Three things to note here. First, while you can obviously code in any language that you want, I would strongly recommend to use English. First, this is what everyone does in the industry. Second, it will help you get help with your code, like here on SO. Second, the level of indentation in your code [smells funny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Try breaking things down into smaller pieces (functions). Third, _"Father can't read 3 characters"_ isn't a problem description. What does "can't" mean? Any errors? What happens?

Comment: In English, the gender-neutral terms 'parent' (grandparent) and 'child' (grandchild) are preferred.

Comment: @domsson Thank you for your answer. When I say "Father can't read 3 characters" I mean that n1 is 1 instead of 3(n2,n3 too) and this is not good because parent should read 3 characters from each pipe and should check if the character sequence is the same. For example, if i read "abc" from pipe1 and "abd" from pipe2 i can't write into fourth file.

Comment: I'm almost sure you aren't closing enough file descriptors in the parent or child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or `fcntl()` with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: I also note that your code is indented to … I think 'insane' is close to appropriate … indented to insane levels.  I eyeball counted 15 levels of close brace `}`; that's ghastly!  It makes the code hard to understand — at minimum.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for your answer
I appreciate your tips and observations even though my code was very hard to understand

Comment: One easy way to reduce the indentation levels is to use `else if` (condition) { …statements… }`  instead of `else { if (condition) { …statements } }`, and aligning `else if` with the controlling `if` (or prior `else if`).  This is recommended by K&R in "The C Programming Language".  If you're constrained by a teacher who insists otherwise, bad luck — know that it is OK in the rest of the world to use `else if` rather than `else { if … }`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, when you transfer data with `read` or `write` you must be prepared to handle short reads and writes.  If you need to communicate in fixed-size chunks then "handle" means to make as many more `read` or `write` calls as are necessary to transfer the rest of the data.  That is rarely an issue for short messages conveyed via pipes, such as you have, but you should be aware.

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile!   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `while((nread=read(fd,buffer,3))>0){`  the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`.  The code is failing to check for errors (nread < 0).   The code wants to read 3 characters, so why the comparison to >0?  wouldn't it be better to check for a returned value of 3?

Comment: regarding: `if(fd<0)
    {
        perror("File");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    else
    {`  since the 'true' side of the `if()` exits the program, there is no need to have `else{`

Comment: regarding: `int ... n1,n2,n3;`  the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`

Comment: for comparing the arrays, strongly suggest using `memcmp()` rather than the many `if()` statements where each character is compared individually

Comment: regarding: `void main(int argc,char **argv){`  Regardless of what some compilers will let you get away with, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char* argv[] )`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding; Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: Thank you everybody for these suggestions. I edited my code and now it works!

Comment: OT: regarding; `if(argc!=5){
        printf("Numero errato di parametri, riprovare.\n");
        exit(1);`  when the user has not input the desired number of command line parameters then output (to stderr) a USAGE message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE %s <file1> <file2> <file3> <outfile4>\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: @user3629249 you're right (about memcmp()) , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the various comments, I note that the three 'figlio' functions are very similar to each other.  They also do not explicitly close enough pipe file descriptors.  Each child has access to all 6 file descriptors from the three pipes, and should, in theory, close all but the one file descriptor they will use to write on.  I created a `figlioGenerale()` function which is passed 3 pairs of file descriptors and closes all except the write end of one of those.  It also gets a tag string to identify which child it represents, and the exit status it should use.  The `else` block which does the work for the parent could sensibly be made into a function too.

Note that I use a multiple assignment in the `fork()` lines:

```
else if ((pid = process[0] = fork()) < 0)
else if ((pid = process[1] = fork()) < 0)
else if ((pid = process[2] = fork()) < 0)
```

That made it unnecessary to add a level of indentation to do the assignment to the `process` array (`processi` in the original).  Indeed, the assignment to `pid` could be avoided if the subsequent tests used `process[N]` instead of `pid` (for an appropriate value of `N` — `0`, `1`, or `2`).

I don't like the use of SIGKILL; it would be better to use SIGTERM or SIGHUP to request processes exit.  There really isn't a need to check which process terminated; it is sufficient to send the terminate signal to each of the three children.  I use standard error for error messages.  I also arranged for the children to ignore SIGPIPE.  That forces the `write()` to return with an error, which is spotted and breaks the writing loop.

There are other changes that could be made — some of them are outlined in the comments.

All that leads to code like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

static void figlioGenerale(char *file, int estatus, const char *figlio,
                           int p_use[], int p_spare1[], int p_spare2[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t process[3];
    int pipe1[2], pipe2[2], pipe3[2], n1, n2, n3;
    int status;
    int fd;

    char buffer1[10], buffer2[10], buffer3[10];
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        printf("Numero errato di parametri, riprovare.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infile1 infile2 infile3 outfile\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pipe(pipe1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2) < 0 || pipe(pipe3) < 0)
    {
        perror("Pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if ((pid = process[0] = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        figlioGenerale(argv[1], 2, "Primo", pipe1, pipe2, pipe3);
    }
    else if ((pid = process[1] = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        figlioGenerale(argv[2], 3, "Secondo", pipe2, pipe1, pipe3);
    }
    else if ((pid = process[2] = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        figlioGenerale(argv[3], 4, "Terzo", pipe3, pipe1, pipe2);
    }
    else
    {
        fd = open(argv[4], O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0666);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
            perror("File");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            close(pipe1[1]);
            close(pipe2[1]);
            close(pipe3[1]);
            while ((n1 = read(pipe1[0], buffer1, 3) == 3) &&
                   (n2 = read(pipe2[0], buffer2, 3) == 3) &&
                   (n3 = read(pipe3[0], buffer3, 3) == 3))
            {
                if (memcmp(buffer1, buffer2, 3) == 0 &&
                    memcmp(buffer1, buffer3, 3) == 0)
                {
                    write(fd, buffer1, 3);
                }
            }
            close(pipe1[0]);    /* Children will get SIGPIPE when writing */
            close(pipe2[0]);
            close(pipe3[0]);
            close(fd);
            kill(process[0], SIGTERM);
            kill(process[1], SIGTERM);
            kill(process[2], SIGTERM);
            while ((pid = wait(&status)) != -1)
                printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", pid, status);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void figlioGenerale(char *file, int estatus, const char *figlio,
                           int p_use[], int p_spare1[], int p_spare2[])
{
    int fd, nread;
    char buffer[3];
    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);       /* Causes write() to return with error on EOF */

    /* Close unused ends of pipes */
    close(p_use[0]);
    close(p_spare1[0]);
    close(p_spare1[1]);
    close(p_spare2[0]);
    close(p_spare2[1]);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s: %s\n", file, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((nread = read(fd, buffer, 3)) > 0)
        {
            if (nread == 3)
            {
                if (write(p_use[1], buffer, nread) != nread)
                    break;
            }
        }
        close(fd);
        close(p_use[1]);
        printf("%s figlio term\n", figlio);
        exit(estatus);
    }
}
```

When run (program `pipe89` compiled from `pipe89.c`), I get outputs such as:

```
$ (
> set -x
> rmk -u pipe89
> pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c pipe89.c pipe.output
> diff pipe89.c pipe.output
> ls -ld pipe89*
> pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
> ls -dl pipe89*
> pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
> pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
> pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
> )
+++ rmk -u pipe89
    gcc -O3   -g      -I./inc    -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes         pipe89.c -o pipe89 -L./lib  -lsoq 
+++ pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c pipe89.c pipe.output
Primo figlio term
Terzo figlio term
Secondo figlio term
PID 24675 exited with status 0x0400
PID 24674 exited with status 0x0300
PID 24673 exited with status 0x0200
+++ diff pipe89.c pipe.output
+++ ls -ld pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.dSYM pipe89.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  13704 Jan 18 14:25 pipe89
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   3444 Jan 18 14:11 pipe89.c
drwxr-xr-x  3 jleffler  staff     96 Jan 18 13:45 pipe89.dSYM
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff    315 Jan 18 14:24 pipe89.sh
+++ pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
Terzo figlio term
Secondo figlio term
PID 24681 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24680 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24679 exited with status 0x000F
+++ ls -dl pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.dSYM pipe89.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  13704 Jan 18 14:25 pipe89
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   3444 Jan 18 14:11 pipe89.c
drwxr-xr-x  3 jleffler  staff     96 Jan 18 13:45 pipe89.dSYM
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff    315 Jan 18 14:24 pipe89.sh
+++ pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
Terzo figlio term
PID 24685 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24686 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24684 exited with status 0x000F
+++ pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
Terzo figlio term
PID 24689 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24690 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24688 exited with status 0x000F
+++ pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
Terzo figlio term
Secondo figlio term
PID 24694 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24693 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24692 exited with status 0x000F
$ rmk pipe89 && pipe89 pipe89.c pipe89.c /dev/null pipe.output
'pipe89' is up to date.
Terzo figlio term
PID 24699 exited with status 0x0400
PID 24698 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24697 exited with status 0x000F
$ rmk pipe89 && pipe89 pipe89.c /dev/null pipe89.c pipe.output
'pipe89' is up to date.
Secondo figlio term
PID 24708 exited with status 0x0300
PID 24709 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24707 exited with status 0x000F
$ rmk pipe89 && pipe89 /dev/null pipe89.c pipe89.c pipe.output
'pipe89' is up to date.
Primo figlio term
PID 24713 exited with status 0x0200
PID 24714 exited with status 0x000F
PID 24715 exited with status 0x000F
$
```

For some reason, when the program is run from a sub-shell, the processes are all terminated by the SIGTERM signal (`0x000F`), but when run directly from the command line, one of the processes (the one reading `/dev/null`) exits with its own exit status.  I have to put that down to the quirks of process scheduling.

It might be better if the pipes were created in a single array of file descriptors, and the child processes were told which pipe descriptor to read from.  The child might duplicate that to file descriptor 1 (standard output — `dup2(pipes[out], STDOUT_FILENO)`) and then simply close all 6 descriptors passed to it.

```
int pipes[6];
if (pipe(&pipes[0]) < 0 ||
    pipe(&pipes[2]) < 0 ||
    pipe(&pipes[4]) < 0)

…

figlioGenerale(argv[1], 2, "Primo",   1, pipes);
figlioGenerale(argv[2], 3, "Secondo", 3, pipes);
figlioGenerale(argv[3], 4, "Terzo",   5, pipes);
```

Comment: About terminating child processes...
The exercise says 
_As soon as one of the children finishes reading its file, all other child processes must also end_
How  can i satisfy this request?
Should I check if a child process terminated while parent is reading from pipes?
(check my new code at the end of question if you want )

Comment: I showed you — when one of the children fails to read (`/dev/null`), it closes its pipe and exits, and the parent fails to read from that child's pipe, and it breaks its reading loop and then sends a signal to all the children.  If you tested the return from `kill()`, you'd usually find that at least one of them fails because that child is dead.  When the children don't report 'Nnnnn figlio term', it means it was signalled.  Sometimes, even when it did report, it was signalled.  The exit status makes that clear. I simply printed the exit status of each child. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If you wanted, you could analyze it with the macros from `<sys/wait.h>` such as `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` and `WIFSIGNALED` and `WTERMSIG` etc.  The 0x000F status indicates signalled and signal number 15 (SIGTERM).  The 0x0400 status indicates exited and exit status 4.  Etc.   —— However, you can change my code (should change my code) to suit any requirements I'm missing, or any local coding rules I'm breaking.  The code more or less works; you can fettle it into final shape.

Comment: Your answer was very complete. I understood many things thanks to you and the other users. 
Thanks for your time, appreciate